# Adding Name From Database as a Column into Data Frame Using an ID (Baseball R)

Tags: r, database, dataframe

Currently I have a data set of the mlb play by play data from 2015-2020, but instead of pitcher names it has IDs like (475054), under the column "pitcher". I have the database from baseball R that works like:

```
playername_lookup(475054)
# A tibble: 1 x 11
  name_first name_last name_given name_suffix name_nick birth_year mlb_played_first key_mlbam key_retro key_bbref
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <lgl>       <chr>          <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
1 Chaz       Roe       Chaz Dani~ NA          NA              1986             2013    475054 roe-c001  roech01  
# ... with 1 more variable: key_fangraphs <dbl>
```

I wish to take the first_name and last_name column and make add the pitchers real name into my dataset. When I try something like this to get the first name

```
Stats$Pitcher_Name_First <- playername_lookup(Stats$pitcher)$name_first
> Stats$Pitcher_Name_First <- playername_lookup(Stats$pitcher)$name_first
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 366304 or 1, not size 3623865.
i Input `..1` is `id == key_mlbam | id == key_retro | id == key_bbref | id == key_fangraphs`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In id == key_mlbam :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In id == key_retro :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In id == key_bbref :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In id == key_fangraphs :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I am met with this problem. However if I simply do:

```
playername_lookup(475054)$name_first
> playername_lookup(475054)$name_first
[1] "Chaz"
```

Which is what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't provide the `playername_lookup()` function. Something which will always work I guess is doing a `for`-loop over all player ID, but that's usually slow.

Comment: Sorry I'm a novice at loops, how would one write a for loop to help for this problem

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(Stats$Pitcher_Name_First)) {
Stats$Pitcher_Name_First[i] <- playername_lookup(Stats$pitcher[i])$name_first
}`